# Receive raw data from Service Bus Trigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am trying to build an Azure Function to process Dynamics 365 messages from an Azure Service Bus. The message is serialized in the *.NET Binary XML* format, so I am trying to receive the message as binary and deserialize it in my code.

The signature of my function method is:

```cs
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "...")] byte[] message,
    ILogger log,
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver)
```

However the functions runtime still fails while trying to parse message, as I get following error:

`The Message with ContentType 'application/msbin1' failed to deserialize to a string with the message: 'Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'RemoteExecutionContext', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts'.'. System.Private.DataContractSerialization: Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'RemoteExecutionContext', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts'.`

How can I receive raw data using `ServiceBusTrigger`?

EDIT 1:
The same error occurs with

```cs
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "...")] Message message,
    ILogger log)
```

I use following versions `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus 4.1.0` and `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.7`.

EDIT 2:
Updated versions to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus 4.1.1` and `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.11` the error is gone, but message length is 0 bytes for both `byte[]` and `Message.Content`

EDIT 3:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       3.0.3160 Commit hash: 00aa7f43cc5c5f15241b5e6e5363256f19ceb990
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.14916.0
```

Comment: If you set the type to `Message` instead of `byte[]` do you get the same error? the `Massage.Body` property should contain the byte array but avoid having Functions try to access the message as it sounds like it is having trouble with that. It would also be helpful to make sure the Functions SDK is up to date and share that version number if you could- if it is on the latest version that will help with reproing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ContentType` needs to be `application/json`. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2154) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your message format is JSON and NOT .NETBinary**

[image]